# Start a transmission-gtk using a cron job

Tags: cron, transmission

I'm trying to start my torrent client using a cron job. Following is the job I added to crontab file(contab -e)

```
00 20 17 07 * transmission-gtk
```

I waited for the time but transmission-gtk didn't startup. but when I try a simple command like "mkdir test". It works. Any ideas friends

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the display for running a gui application through cron. So your line would be:

```
00 20 17 07 * env DISPLAY=:0.0 transmission-gtk
```

Check this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for more details.

Comment: * * * * * export DISPLAY=":0.0" && for app in "eiskaltdcpp-qt" "transmission-gtk" "nicotine";do ps aux|grep -v grep|grep "$app";done||"$app" &

________________________________________________________________________________________Anyone knows please why this cronjob does not launch the transmission please? only @Ashish command worked.. Other apps from that command it launch, but not transmission, even ps aux autput is empty and the command after pipes i correct.