# Transmission Gtk-WARNING **: <time> cannot open display: :0.0

Tags: gnome, cron, transmission, schedule

Ubuntu 22.04

I'm trying to use crontab to launch Transmission at 22:04 and kill it at 07:00.
To launch it at 22:04, I use:

```
04 22 * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 transmission-gtk
```

But I get the error:

```
(transmission-gtk:21925): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:04:01.301: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I've also tried:

```
04 22 * * * DISPLAY=:0 transmission-gtk
```

but I get the same error (without the last `.0`)

How can I launch Transmission-gtk from crontab?
I want to do this as I've noticed that Transmission uses network resources even when in the alternate speed-limit mode. I realise I could use something else like qbittorrent, but there must be a way of launching Transmission at certain times? Gnome-scheduler no longer seems to be in the Ubuntu repositories.

The [question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499108/start-a-transmission-gtk-using-a-cron-job) hasn't received an answer to the problem.

Comment: That wont work. Please install `transmission-daemon`.  See https://linux.die.net/man/1/transmission-daemon#:~:text=transmission%2Ddaemon%20is%20a%20daemon,transmission%2Dremote(1).  and you can enable and disable the systemd unt from crontab  `~/.config/transmission-daemon` for the configuration.

Comment: also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo